# WCF service with NLB

Tags: wcf, load-balancing

I have a WCF service, which is currently hosted on two servers behind an NLB.
The two server addresses are (for example) `t001.mydomain.com` and `t002.mydomain.com` and the NLB address is `services.mydomain.com`. Both `t001` and `t002` have an SSL certificate for `services.mydomain.com`

We moved several `ASMX` services to a new `WCF` model. When I first put the services on both servers I had a problem consuming the WSDL. One service was working, but the others gave me an error that they could not create a secure connection, since the certificate was invalid.

I put the URLs in to Chrome and I noticed that the service that was working had a WSDL URI like this: `http://services.mydomain.com/services/service1.svc` and the services that did not work had a URI of `http://t001.mydomain.com/services/service2.svc`. So I get why the certificate was not valid for these services.

What I did to fix this (after looking at the differences in the config files) is add the following line to the config files of the services that were not working:

`<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />`

Now, I kind of understand why this works. I know its a solutions, but I dont know if it is THE solution to my issue.

Is this the way around this issue? Is there a better / more recommended way to get around this? Maybe someone can point me at an authoretive source explaining this, since I couldnt really find one.

Answer (score 2):

This did not work, because cert. Domain part is different.  See

A thing about host names - some systems will not work properly unless you use the fully qualified domain name. Others are not so picky. In any case - the certificate's Subject DN should uniquely describe the service, application or server it represents.

From this post [Mutual WCF certificate authentication/SSL in cluster environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519527/mutual-wcf-certificate-authentication-ssl-in-cluster-environment)

More details can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439393(v=exchg.80).aspx